# Angular check overflow for element in controller

Tags: angular, dom, angular-material, tooltip

For a grid there are field that possibly have an Ellipsis since the content could be to large.

In that case a tooltip should be shown with the full content.
In the component code i have written a method to calculate for an element if it has an ellipsis or not but when passing the dom element to the component with `this` it refers to the component.

How can i achieve this? Problem is that this is in a grid and i cannot ad an `elementRef` for each row. My code so far:

```
<div [matTooltip]="item.displayname" [matTooltipDisabled]="hasNoOverflow(this)">
            {{item.displayname}}</div>

hasNoOverflow(element) {
    if (element.offsetHeight < element.scrollHeight ||
        element.offsetWidth < element.scrollWidth) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at Angular directives

Comment: What exactly is your element though?

Comment: the DIV where the displayname is shown

Answer (score 0):

I was able to pass the dom element to the Component:

```
<div #el [matTooltip]="item.displayname" [matTooltipDisabled]="hasNoOverflow(el)">
        {{item.displayname}}</div>
```